# Add hash to set member -- node-redis

Tags: node.js, redis

Redis has me very confused. I simply need a set of users. The keys for the users will be their `userID`s:

```
  var user = userID;
```

I then want hash values set for these users, and right now I only have one - `socketID`:

```
  // add first user
  redis.sadd("users", user);
  redis.hmset(user, "socketID", socket.id);
```

However, `user` gets added to the set `users`. But the hash for `socketID` isn't there. It seems like when I do the `hmset`, it's getting set on some other `user` key unrelated to the on in the `sadd` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally understand what's going on (in redis, not quite in life):

```
  var user = userID;

  // add first user
  redis.sadd("users", user);
  redis.hmset("users:"+user, "socketID", socket.id, "userID", userID);
```

This [list of examples](http://ejosh.co/de/2012/07/node-js-socket-io-and-redis-beginners-tutorial-server-side/) helped me understand `node-redis` syntax finally.

Comment: _finally understand what's going on (in redis, not quite in life)_ good point!